# Cannot find ethernet in new Xenial install

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet

I have a clean install of Xenial on a VMware system, and the ethernet device is not being found.  (Since I cannot ssh into the box, I cannot cut-and-paste output into this window, so please bear with me if I elide some of the command output).

```
% ifup eth0
Unknown interface eth0
% ifconfig eth0 up
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
% sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: ens32
       version: 01
       serial: 00:50:56:a5:1e:b5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix ... [many capabilities]
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI ... [more less-relevant config]
       resources: irq:18 memory:d1020000-d103ffff memory:d1000000-d100ffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:d1010000-d101ffff

% lspci -nnk | grep -i -A2 net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:100f] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: VMware PRO/1000 MT Single Port Adapter [15ad:0750]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000

But nothing is using the e1000 driver:
% lsmod | grep e1000
e1000            135168 0

And the driver is not blacklisted:
% grep e1000 /etc/modprobe.d/*
%
```

I'm at a loss.  If anyone could lend me a clue, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try doing ifconfig by itself and see if there's anything along the lines of enpXsXX

Comment: This is correct, but you must add the -a parameter, because if you don't, ifconfig will not show show the interfaces in down state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be many causes for this and your information is not enough for a full troubleshoot.

But if you run 'ifconfig -a' it will show you all the available network interfaces in the system.

The most probable result is that 'ifconfig -a' will show you the card with a different name. It may be 'emX' instead of 'ethX' for example. You should configure and start using the new interface.

If no ethernet card appears, most probably it will be a driver problem, but you should check the 'ifconfig -a' output before investigating this route.

Comment: Thank you--that did it.  The interface is named ens32 instead of eth0.